# How can I access value in another function when there is no return at python?

Tags: python

Currently I was stuck at my code and couldn't figure it out. My code is:

```
*def patientRegistration():
    cont = "Y"
    totalPCR = 0
    totalAntigen = 0
    totalChild = 0
    totalSenior = 0
    while cont == "Y":
        print ("Please input your details below:")
        name = input("Name:")
        age = eval(input("Age:"))
        gender = input("Gender[F/M]:")
        type = eval(input("Type[1/2]:"))
        if (type == 1):
            #totalPCR += 1
            if (age >= 1 and age <= 10):
                totalChild += 1
                totalPCR += 1
            elif (age > 60):
                totalSenior += 1
                totalPCR += 1
        elif (type == 2):
            #totalAntigen += 1
            if (age >= 1 and age <= 10):
                totalChild += 1
                totalAntigen += 1
            elif (age > 60):
                totalSenior += 1
                totalAntigen += 1
        cont= input("Cont[Y/N]:")
    return totalPCR, totalAntigen, totalChild, totalSenior
def totalSales (totalPCR, totalAntigen, totalChildPCR, totalChildAntigen, totalSeniorPCR, totalSeniorAntigen):
    pricePCR = 450
    priceAntigen = 180
    print ("Total Sales: RM")
    print ("Breakdown of Sales -")
    print ("PCR: RM")
    print ("Antigen: RM")
    return totalSales, pcrSales, antigenSales*
```

I would like to find out the *totalChildPCR* and so on, but I couldn't figure it out besides adding return at *patientRegistration()*. Is there any way I could make it without adding an extra return value at *patientRegistration()*?

Comment: I think your two options are either return the values or pass as an argument a mutable object that you will update within the function.

Comment: You can do this by creating global varaible. when you create a variable inside a function, that variable is local, and can only be used inside that function.
To create a global variable inside a function, you can use the global keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating global varaible. when you create a variable inside a function, that variable is local, and can only be used inside that function. To create a global variable inside a function, you can use the global keyword.

```
 def patientRegistration():
        ...
        global totalChild = 0
```